# Local Activity manager issue in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I use Local activity manager in my tab group activity class for switch over b/w various activity in Tab, for example from my main Tab1 i switch over b/w following activities Act1->Act2->Act3.

Where in act2 i call web service based on data from tab1, then i move to Act 3. But when i click back button Act2 onCreate will invoke again.

I found that there is issue in android local activity manager and implemented correponding fix code in `destroy` method.

Here is overall tabgroup activity code..

```
  import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;

/**
 * The purpose of this Activity is to manage the activities in a tab.
 * Note: Child Activities can handle Key Presses before they are seen here.
 * @author Eric Harlow
 */
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {

    private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        if (mIdList == null) mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * This is called when a child activity of this one calls its finish method. 
     * This implementation calls {@link LocalActivityManager#destroyActivity} on the child activity
     * and starts the previous activity.
     * If the last child activity just called finish(),this activity (the parent),
     * calls finish to finish the entire group.
     */
  @Override
  public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
      LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
      int index = mIdList.size()-1;

      if (index < 1) {
          finish();
          return;
      }
      System.out.println("Destroy called");
      boolean rt=destroy(mIdList.get(index),manager);
      System.out.println("Destroy called"+rt);
//      manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
      mIdList.remove(index); index--;
      String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
      Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
      Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
      setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
  }

  /**
   * Starts an Activity as a child Activity to this.
   * @param Id Unique identifier of the activity to be started.
   * @param intent The Intent describing the activity to be started.
   * @throws android.content.ActivityNotFoundException.
   */
  public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {     
      Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
      if (window != null) {
          mIdList.add(Id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
      }    
  }

  /**
   * The primary purpose is to prevent systems before android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
   * from calling their default KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK during onKeyDown.
   */
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }

  /**
   * Overrides the default implementation for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK 
   * so that all systems call onBackPressed().
   */
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          onBackPressed();
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
  }

  /**
   * If a Child Activity handles KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.
   * Simply override and add this method.
   */
  public void  onBackPressed  () {
      int length = mIdList.size();
      if ( length > 1) {
          Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
          System.out.println("Activity Being close"+current.getLocalClassName());
          current.finish();
      }  
  }
  public boolean destroy(String id,LocalActivityManager activityManager) {

        if(activityManager != null){
            activityManager.destroyActivity(id, false);
            // http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12359
            // http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/LocalActivityManager.java
            try {
                final Field mActivitiesField = LocalActivityManager.class.getDeclaredField("mActivities");
                if(mActivitiesField != null){
                    mActivitiesField.setAccessible(true);
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    final Map<String, Object> mActivities = (Map<String, Object>)mActivitiesField.get(activityManager);
                    if(mActivities != null){
                        mActivities.remove(id);
                    }
                    final Field mActivityArrayField = LocalActivityManager.class.getDeclaredField("mActivityArray");
                    if(mActivityArrayField != null){
                        mActivityArrayField.setAccessible(true);
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        final ArrayList<Object> mActivityArray = (ArrayList<Object>)mActivityArrayField.get(activityManager);
                        if(mActivityArray != null){
                            for(Object record : mActivityArray){
                                final Field idField = record.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
                                if(idField != null){
                                    idField.setAccessible(true);
                                    final String _id = (String)idField.get(record);
                                    if(id.equals(_id)){
                                        mActivityArray.remove(record);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

i don`t know how to prevent restart activity.If any one knows the solutions help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: I am having same problem..any can solve this..?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue in following way but i don`t know whether it cause any problem,

```
 @Override
  public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
      LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
      int index = mIdList.size()-1;

      if (index < 1) {
          finish();
          return;
      }
      System.out.println("Destroy called");
      destroy(mIdList.get(index),manager);

        mIdList.remove(index); index--;
        String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
        Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
        Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP));
        setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
  }
```

simply restore the activity using intent flag, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP which resume our activity by bringing it to front without restarting it.

Comment: here how to get midList values